# antlr4 assistance

Tags: parsing, intellij-idea, antlr4, intellij-plugin

I'm new to antlr4, and am trying to write a code to look through a .txt and find keywords (set to "PARTY" for testing) and then store everything after, stopping at a new line (excluding the '|' symbol).

I'm running the code in IntelliJ with the antlr4 plugin, and for some reason it's reading the first line, making a parsing tree for it and then stopping.

[image]

Comment: The parser produces an error. Probably because you defined that every line should start with `PARTY` but your input does not start with said keyword.

Answer (score 0):

According to your grammar, each line should start with one or more occurrences of the keyword `PARTY`, but your first and second line don't start with that. That's why it's complaining about the "missing P".

Another problem is that since you're hiding the `NWL` tokens, you can't use them in the grammar. If you want newlines to be significant in your grammar, you should not hide them. In other words you should remove the `{channel=HIDDEN;}` bit.

Comment: thank you!  I appreciate that and have taken that part out.

I'm still getting the same problem though, in that it's not going past the first line.

Comment: @Steve Sorry, I didn't really look too closely at the error message. Looks like the immediate problem is that your first line (and the second) doesn't start with `PARTY`, but your grammar says each line should start with `PARTY`.

Comment: The reason it is not going past the first line is that the `file` rule is completely matched when the parser hits the first non-matching line. So the parser stops. To force all lines to be 'read', specify that in your `file` rule:  `file : lines+ EOF`